# Why does pipe() take an array instead of pointers to two ints?

Tags: c, linux, unix

The [pipe() function](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) has a signature of `int pipe(int fildes[2])`. The `filedes` parameter is used so the function can return two ints (where `filedes[0]` gets set to the file descriptor of the pipe's read end, and `filedes[1]` to the pipe's write end).

I'm trying to figure out why this API was designed to take a pointer to an array, instead of two pointers like this: `int pipe(int *read, int *write)`. It seems like taking a pointer to an array is more error prone than taking two different pointers, and it also makes it impossible to use if the two given ints aren't next to each other in memory.

Is there a specific reason that the `pipe()` API is designed the way it is?

Comment: A possible drawback to the hypothetical `int pipe(int *read, int *write)` API is that it would allow the same pointer to be passed for both parameters.

Comment: This is really something that only the original designers and authors could answer with any certainty. Anything anyone else could say is pure speculation.

Comment: With that said: My *speculation* is that arguments needs space (memory or registers), and space was very limited on the early computers where UNIX and the `pipe` call was developed. So better pass a single argument than multiple arguments to save a few bytes. It's also less to write which also saves some bytes, and also saves time when reading the source code from e.g. tape.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html <- maybe the NOTES section will be slightly enlightening. We're talking architectural constraints in System V times (198x) and earlier.

Comment: @eeze there could just be a protection to check equality of write and read ptrs, so not really a problem

Comment: Re “I'm trying to figure out why this API was designed to take a pointer to an array”: `int fildes[2]` does not declare a pointer to an array. Nominally, it declares an array, and it is adjusted to be a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @dratenik [Definitely earlier](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html#tag_16_362_11): "Derived from Issue 1 of the SVID."  The first version of the SVID was published in 1983 at the latest - see http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/vol1a.pdf for the copyright history.

Comment: @AndrewHenle probably much earlier, pipes were a core feature of early Unix, it might be interesting to see the very original syscall. Hmm, where to find that...

Comment: @EricPostpischil As the type of a function argument, `int filedes[2]`, `int filedes[]` and `int *filedes` are all the same, no?

Comment: @dratenik `pipe()` doesn't seem to predate C, as I can't find `pipe()` in [this B reference](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/masterindex.html).  If `pipe()` doesn't exist in a B implementation given half-a-century of opportunity to backport it, it's probably safe to assume `pipe()` wasn't implemented in B.  So `pipe()` probably wasn't implemented until 1973 or so when the first versions of C were born.

Comment: @AndrewHenle https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6/usr/doc/man/man2/pipe.2 <- I found 1973, this version returned the two file descriptors in two separate registers ... or alternatively used the array?

Comment: @dratenik  You seem to have nailed down the origin of `pipe()`.  It seems it was developed to [support process pipelines in `sh`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6/usr/doc/man/man1/sh.1#L59) given the "The Shell has a syntax
to set up a linear array of processes
connected by pipes." words from [your link](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6/usr/doc/man/man2/pipe.2#L49)  Too bad there's no documented reasoning.

Comment: @eeze: Mostly. There are some technical differences that do not show up in that simple case. For example, the parameter declarations `int (*a)[]` and `int a[][]` are different. The first is allowed, but the second violates a constraint in the C standard. Although the second would be adjusted to the first, an array declaration must not have an element of incomplete type, and the missing array size in the second `[]` makes it incomplete. But you can have a pointer to incomplete type. So `int (*a)[]` is allowed. But my point is a pointer to an array is not `int a[2]`; it would be `int (*a)[2]`.

Comment: (cont)  Note also though that your link has the `pipe(fildes) int fildes[2];` "K&R style" function definition so the use of an `int[2]` array dates back to what's almost certainly the original `pipe()` implementation.

Comment: @eeze: The reason I point this out is the misapplied terminology made me think your question might be based on that. It is confusing. Reading the whole question, it seems like you are merely asking about a different between a pointer to (the first of) two `int` versus two pointers to `int`, but the mistaken terminology can confuse readers.